# Problema matriz 3x3

Tags: java

Desconozco para que sirve lo que pone en el segundo bucle for
 j

```
        int matriz[][]=new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
            **for(int j=0;j<matriz[0].length;j++){**
                matriz[i][j]=(i*matriz.length)+(j+1);
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");



             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

La matriz se puede definir como un arreglo de arreglos, o arreglo bidimensional.

Por esta razón primero debemos recorrer el primer arreglo (el del bucle i), el cual va a pasar por cada una de las columnas de la matriz.

Y luego hay que recorrer el de las filas (el del bucle j), el cual pasa posición por posición en la columna que esta pasando el primer bucle (el de la i).

te dejo este link con información mas detallada al respecto. http://escueladeprogramacion.es/snippets/Java/Algoritmos/Matrices/Recorrer.html

Answer (score 0):

El primer `for` con indice `i` lo utilizas para recorrer las filas de la matriz y el segundo `for` con indice `j` para recorrer las columnas de cada una de estas filas.

El resultado de tu rutina sera algo como esto: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Puedes darte cuenta de lo que mencione agregando un salto de linea despues de cada loop en el primer `for`:

```
int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
        matriz[i][j] = (i * matriz.length) + (j + 1);
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

La salida sera:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

La instruccion `j < matriz[0].length` se utiliza solo para tener contexto del largo de las filas de tu matriz, ya que su tamaño podria cambiar a 5x5 y no tendria sentido colocar en duro un `3`. Ahi es mejor sacar ese valor del largo de alguna de las filas, que en este caso lo hace de la fila con indice `0`. Aun asi, creo que para darle mayor sentido a la iteracion lo que haria es usar el mismo indice `i` en vez de `0` para que no quede un codigo confuso, por ej: `j < matriz[i].length`.